# How to test nodejs concurrent Request

Tags: node.js, concurrency

I want to write a simple code to test nodejs Concurrency when it receives many requests.

And I use **loadtest** module for simulate send many requests to server with this command :

```
loadtest -c 10 --rps 200 http://localhost:3000/
```

my simple code that write in server.js :

```
var http = require('http');
var server = http.createServer();
var cun=0;
var step=0;       

function handleRequest(req,res) {

console.log(step++);
        while(100000000>cun){
            cun++;
        }
        cun=0;
}

server.on('request', handleRequest);
server.listen(3000);
```

but requests is wait until while loop is down

and know to solve this problem I should use callback function , but don't know How do write it.

Comment: Do you want to simulate the request handler taking some time before it sends back a response? Use `setTimeout` for that.

Comment: thanks for response,I have a web app that often my server receives 50,0000 requests in a moment, I want use nodejs to receive,process and response concurrent requests BUT requests wait in a queue until last request process is down and I don't know how to handle this problem

Comment: The code you are posting doesn't make sense (for one, you are blocking the event loop, and secondly, you don't actually send back any responses). So perhaps you should post the actual code, or better describe what exactly it is you are trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

```
var http = require('http');
var url = require("url");
var server = http.createServer();

function handleRequest(req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain'});

var params = url.parse(request.url, true).query;
var input = params.number;

/*
1- Use input param in a algorithm and process it
2- Insert data in to the db
3- select on db and return to the client
*/  

  res.end();
}
server.on('request', handleRequest);
server.listen(3000);
```

PROBLEM :
All requests wait in a queue until last request process(process-insert-select) is down